# bash script on copying file that is modified very recent

Tags: bash

I need a script to get the latest updated file and copy over to remote servers. Also, the script should terminate once run itself.

I have tried with While loop, it does copy but I am unable to stop the scripts once it completes its job. or I missed something not known to me.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="/opt/testdir/file.txt"
LATEST=$(ls -Art | tail -n 1)
while [ $LATEST != $FILE ] 
do 
rsync -avz $LATEST 192.168.20.20:/opt/testdir/.
done
```

i) file should copy to remote server and whenever script runs it copies over to remote server same file overwrite.

Comment: what is the purpose of the `FILE` variable and test?

Comment: I want to copy the file over an over again to remote servers if it modified.

Comment: var $FILE is the file of interest to be copy.

Comment: Huh? You're copying `$LATEST`, not `$FILE`. `$LATEST` will be the name of the most recent file in the current directory (which might or might not be /opt/testdir), and the loop will copy it over and over as long as that's not "/opt/testdir/file.txt" (which it will *never* be; even if that's the latest file, `$LATEST` will be just "file.txt"). The code, as written, doesn't make any sense. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @emadahmed [Don’t use `ls` like that](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and quote your variables!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with using `inotify` tools

```
# monitor current directory ./
# and get dir/file paths on these file-system events:
# - close_write (file written and closed)
# - create (file created)
# - moved_to (file moved to here)

inotifywait \
  --quiet \
  --monitor \
  --event close_write \
  --event create \
  --event moved_to \
  --format '%w%f' \
  ./ \
  | {
    # loop through all files
    # as inotifywait may return multiple files (one per line)
    while read -r LATEST; do
      rsync \
        --archive \
        --compress \
        --verbose \
        "${LATEST}" \
        192.168.20.20:/opt/testdir/.
    done
  }
```

See:

- [inotifywait man-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/inotifywait.1.html)